# Ability to provide a mapping for datatypes when using DataTable in C#

Tags: c#

I am filling a dataset from a SQL server database using `SqlDataAdapter` in C# 4.0. Is there a way so that I can be able to provide an alternate mapping for the `GUID` DBDataType to String.

I need the GUID's to be interpreted as string in the resultant datatable, so if there can be a mapping which automatically sets the GUID to String i can consume that feature, else i have to recreate the datatable and populate the values using linq or other methods, which will be a performance hit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen a way to do a mapping like this with the ADO.NET classes.  Instead of trying to map from one data type to another in the `SqlDataAdapter`, you could modify your query to convert the `uniqueidentifier` to `varchar`:

```
select cast(YourGuidColumn as varchar(36)) as YourGuidColumn, ...
```

Comment: The query that i have is dynamically generated one, so i cannot infer the column data types from the input.

Comment: Understood.  If you do not find an alternative, it is still possible to determine the type of the column using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` - the value of `DATA_TYPE` for the column will be `uniqueidentifier`.  You could use this information when constructing the query.